# WebSite in application and Refresh button

Tags: iphone, ios, web, refresh

How to I show website on my tab in application?

And create refresh button

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please make consider editing it specifying what is it exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to show website in my application for exmple:have tab with name google and when I click it the tab show to me google

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add a UIWebView to a UIViewController. Put this in your viewDidLoad method:

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
[wv loadRequest:req];
[self.view addSubview:wv];
```

Regarding the refresh button: Make sure 'wv' is defined in your .h file and use this method:

```
- (IBAction)refresh
{
    [wv reload];
}
```